# Scientific applications of the tikzducks

Tags: tikzducks

Are the `tikzducks` used to explain any scientific stuff?

*I'm currently compiling a list of such applications for an upcoming talk, so even if you are not able to share your image, it would be helpful to hear examples of topics the `tikzducks` are used for.*

> Please note, that no ducks may be harmed in your answers

Comment: may be in explaining the relative speed (rather than cars).

Comment: @touhami Good idea! One could even use the duckmobil from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391258/36296 :)

Comment: in genetics ([Sex linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_linkage))

Comment: Closely related, in an opposite sense: Using ballet to illustrate science. I've seen this live: https://www.ted.com/talks/john_bohannon_dance_vs_powerpoint_a_modest_proposal

Comment: Isn't this question just off-topic? Ducks are flooding the site and are used as rep generators. :-/

Comment: @Johannes_B If you are worried about the rep, I can turn it into a CW question. But I don't think it is off topic - it is about the application of a package, for which I like to collect examples in preparation of a talk at a tex user group meeting.

Comment: No, it's fine. I just feel a bit like Henri and see ducks everywhere.

Comment: `\let\qed=\duck` gets a duck at the end of every proof.

Comment: @LoopSpace qed is short for `quack erat demonstrandum`, isn't it?

Comment: @Johannes_B On a more practical note: you know that you can configure your tex.se account to hide questions with tags which are on your ignore tag list? I am doing this for example with lyx and it works really well.

Comment: @samcarter Or `quod erat duck`.

Comment: Not a duck, but a closely-related dog: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-9112/24/12/028/pdf

Comment: Community just flagged this question with "More than 10 answers posted to this question in the past 7 days". First time I see this flag. ;-)

Comment: @MartinScharrer Yeah!

Answer (score 32):

It is possible to form a grammatical English sentence of length *n*, using only the words "duck" and "ducks", for all values of *n*.

Using `tikzducks` perhaps makes the visualization of the structures easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\Ducks}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2]\duck\begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]\duck\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}}
\let\ducks\Ducks
\usepackage{gb4e}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
For any $n$, there is a grammatical English sentence of length $n$ consisting only of some combination of the words \emph{duck} and \emph{ducks}.  
\end{theorem}
Here are the first $6$ (with very simplified trees).
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{exe}
\ex Duck!
\ex Ducks duck.
\ex Ducks duck ducks.
\ex Ducks ducks duck duck.
\ex Ducks ducks duck duck ducks.
\ex Ducks ducks ducks duck duck duck.
\end{exe}
\columnbreak\setcounter{exx}{0}
\begin{exe}
\ex Duck!
\ex \Ducks{} duck.
\ex \Ducks{} duck \ducks.
\ex \Ducks{} \ducks{} duck duck.
\ex \Ducks{} \ducks{} duck duck \ducks.
\ex \Ducks{} \ducks{} \ducks{} duck duck duck.
\end{exe}
\end{multicols}
\setcounter{exx}{0}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{exe}
\ex\begin{forest}
[S [NP\\pro ] [VP [V\\duck ]]]
\end{forest}
\ex\begin{forest}
[S [NP\\\Ducks ] [VP [V\\duck]]]
\end{forest}
\ex\begin{forest}
[S [NP\\\Ducks ] [VP [V\\duck ] [NP\\\ducks ]]]
\end{forest}
\ex\begin{forest}
[S [NP [NP\\\Ducks ][S [NP\\\Ducks ] [VP [V\\duck]]]] [VP [V\\duck]]]
\end{forest}
\ex
\begin{forest}
[S [NP [NP\\\Ducks ][S [NP\\\Ducks ] [VP [V\\duck]]]] [VP [V\\duck ] [NP\\\ducks ]]]
\end{forest}
\ex
\begin{forest}
[S [NP [NP\\\Ducks ][S [NP [NP\\\Ducks ][S [NP\\\Ducks ] [VP [V\\duck]]]] [VP [V\\duck]]]][VP [V\\duck]]]
\end{forest}
\end{exe}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Wow! The only stopping criterion is how often one can say ducks duck in a row without getting confused :)

Comment: Now we just need a [tikzbuffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo) package.

Comment: Now I would want to see ducks in all linguistics papers! This is just so cool XD

Answer (score 30):

### Using the wake of a duck to explain the opening angle of Cherenkov light

(See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/9483 for more details about this analogy)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[scale=0.5,xshift=-23,yshift=320] 
    \duck
  \end{scope}  
  \draw[black] 
    (10,6) circle (4.45)
    (9,6) circle (4)  
    (8,6) circle (3.55)
    (7,6) circle (3.1)  
    (6,6) circle (2.68)
    (5,6) circle (2.24)  
    (4,6) circle (1.8)
    (3,6) circle (1.35)  
    (2,6) circle (0.9)            
    (1,6) circle (0.47)      
  ; 
  \draw[blue,thick] 
    (12,0) -- (0,6) -- (12,12)
    (0,6) -- (15,6)
    (8.15,1.96) -- (10,6) -- (8.15,10.04)
    (8.8,6)arc(180:120:1.345551)
  ;
  \draw[thick,rotate=26.5,blue,->]   (4,5.35) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=26.5,blue,->]   (6,5.35) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=26.5,blue,->]   (8,5.35) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=26.5,blue,->]   (10,5.35) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=26.5,blue,->]   (12,5.35) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=26.5,blue,->]   (14,5.35) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=-26.5,blue,<-]   (-1.4,4.55) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=-26.5,blue,<-]   (0.6,4.55) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=-26.5,blue,<-]   (2.6,4.55) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=-26.5,blue,<-]   (4.6,4.55) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=-26.5,blue,<-]   (6.6,4.55) -- ++(0,0.8);
  \draw[thick,rotate=-26.5,blue,<-]   (8.6,4.55) -- ++(0,0.8);  
  \node at (9.35,6.4) {\Large $\Theta_{c}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Improved 3D version by @marmot

from https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43703817#43703817

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.5,xshift=-20,yshift=-20]
\duck
\end{scope}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-30}{40}{45}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\foreach \X in {1,...,10}
{
\draw[black] (0,0,\X) circle ({\X*0.45});
\draw[thick,blue,->] (0,{\X*0.45},\X) -- ++(0,0.32,{-0.3*0.45});
\draw[thick,blue,->] (0,{-\X*0.45},\X) -- ++(0,-0.32,{-0.3*0.45});
}
\draw[blue,thick]
(0,4.5,10) -- (0,0,0) -- (0,-4.5,10)
(0,0,0) -- (0,0,14.5) coordinate (P)
(0,4.5,10) -- (0,0,14.5) -- (0,-4.5,10);
\coordinate (M) at (0,0,10);
\end{scope}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-120}{150}{0}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,red]
\draw (M) arc (-90:-57:3) node[midway,right,yshift=-5]{\Large $\Theta_{c}$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. A superluminal duck!

Answer (score 30):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\begin{document}
\section*{Length contraction}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 $v=0$ & $v=0.5\cdot c$ & $v=0.9\cdot c$\\
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[use as bounding box](0,0) rectangle (2.4,2.4);
 \duck
 \end{tikzpicture}
 &
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[use as bounding box](-0.25,0) rectangle (2.15,2.4);
 \pgftransformcm{sqrt(1-0.5^2)}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}} 
 \duck
 \end{tikzpicture}
 &
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[use as bounding box](-0.5,0) rectangle (1.9,2.4);
 \pgftransformcm{sqrt(1-0.9^2)}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}} 
 \duck
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}\\
Don't worry, the ducks are fine!
\end{document}
```

Just for fun: rocket ducks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,fadings}
\newcommand{\RocketDuck}{ \duck
 \shade[ball color=blue,opacity=0.15] (1,1) circle (1.3);
 \fill [color=orange,path fading=east] (3.9,-0.75) 
 -- ++({3*cos(25)},{3*sin(25)}) arc (25:-25:3) 
 -- ++ ({-3*cos(25)},{3*sin(25)}) -- cycle;
 \shade[bottom color=red,top color=red!25!white] (4,0.25) arc (90:-90:0.25 and 1) -- (-2,-1.75) 
 arc (-90:90:0.25 and 1) -- cycle;
 \shade[bottom color=blue,top color=blue!25!white] (-2,-1.75) arc (-90:90:0.25 and 1) 
 -- (-3.2,-0.75) -- cycle;
}
\begin{document}
\section*{Length contraction (Don't worry, the ducks are fine!)}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[ultra thick,-latex] (-1,1.8) -- (-3,1.8) node[midway,above]{$v=0$};
 \RocketDuck
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
 \draw[ultra thick,-latex] (-1,1.8) -- (-3,1.8) node[pos=0.45,above]{$v=0.5\cdot c$};
 \pgftransformcm{sqrt(1-0.5^2)}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}} 
 \RocketDuck
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-10cm]
 \draw[ultra thick,-latex] (-1,1.8) -- (-3,1.8) node[pos=0.45,above]{$v=0.9\cdot c$};
 \pgftransformcm{sqrt(1-0.9^2)}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}} 
 \RocketDuck
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ducks in Space? :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are worried about egreg's reaction, right? He's a bit allergic to space(s)... ;-)

Answer (score 26):

Here's my math joke about the formula calculating the volume of cylinder/disk which might be easier remembered by students/pupils:

The `chef` duck is perfectly suited for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikzducks}


\begin{document}
\boldmath
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster rows=2,height=15cm,raster equal height]
\begin{tcolorbox}[height=0.5\linewidth,valign=center,halign=center,width=0.5\linewidth,enhanced, fontupper={\large},colback=yellow!20!white, circular arc, drop shadow]

  What is the formula for the volume of a cylinder with

  \begin{itemize}
  \item radius $z$ 
  \item[]  and
  \item height $a$
  \end{itemize}


  ?
\end{tcolorbox} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[drop shadow,colback=yellow!20!white]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
\duck[chef=white!95!yellow,
rollingpin=brown!80!black, think={$ V = pi \cdot z \cdot z \cdot a$}]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster} 
\end{document}
```

No ducks were harmed → they are just the pizza chefs...

Comment: can ducks be used rather than rabbit in Fibonacci sequence ?

Comment: You last statement is only true of the duck chefs are not forced to make pineapple pizza :)

Comment: @samcarter: They are not physically harmed... although being forced to use delicious pizza dough in conjunction with pineapple could make them mad, of course ;-)

Comment: I was about asking a stupid question about nomenclature ;-)

Comment: @AlexG: Nomenclature? Good pizza vs. Evil pizza ?

Comment: No,more stupid: *a* vs *h* :-)

Comment: @AlexG: Imagine 'altitude' (*a*) as 'height' (*h*) :-P (Yes, I know, `altitude` is not the correct term ;-))

Answer (score 26):

In order to add some chemistry to this list, here is a laboratory duck helping to explain the concept of chirality.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{black!20!white}{
\begin{tabular}{c:c}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1,transform shape]
    \duck[glasses=gray,tshirt=black!10!white,jacket=white]
    \path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw,clip] (-0.5,1.75) to[rounded corners=2pt]++(0,-1)to[rounded corners=2pt]++(-1,-2.5)to[rounded
corners=2pt, bend right=10pt]++(3,0) to[rounded corners=2pt]++(-1,2.5)--++(0,1)++(-0.5,0) circle [x radius=0.5, y radius=0.1];
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,fill=green!90!black](-1.6,-2) rectangle (1.6,{1cm-2cm});
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,fill=green!90!white] (0,1cm-2cm) circle [x radius=1.5cm-(1cm-0.25cm)*0.4 , y radius=0.1 cm];
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (0,0) circle (5pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (-0.2,0.75) circle (3pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (0.25,1.15) circle (2pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (0,1.4) circle (4pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (-0.25,-0.5) circle (3pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (0.25,-1) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \duck[glasses=gray,tshirt=black!10!white,jacket=white]
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw,clip] (-0.5,1.75) to[rounded corners=2pt]++(0,-1)to[rounded corners=2pt]++(-1,-2.5)to[rounded
corners=2pt, bend right=10pt]++(3,0) to[rounded corners=2pt]++(-1,2.5)--++(0,1)++(-0.5,0) circle [x radius=0.5, y radius=0.1];
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,fill=green!90!black](-1.6,-2) rectangle (1.6,{1cm-2cm});
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,fill=green!90!white] (0,1cm-2cm) circle [x radius=1.5cm-(1cm-0.25cm)*0.4 , y radius=0.1 cm];
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (0,0) circle (5pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (-0.2,0.75) circle (3pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (0.25,1.15) circle (2pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (0,1.4) circle (4pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (-0.25,-0.5) circle (3pt);
\path[xshift=35,yshift=20,scale=0.2,rotate=-10,draw=black,  line width=0.2pt, fill=green!70!white] (0.25,-1) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\[0.25cm]
\scalebox{0.6}{\chemfig{A-[:30](-[:90]B)(<:[:-10]C)(<[:-50]D)}}
&
\scalebox{.6}{\chemfig{A-[:150](-[:90]B)(<:[:190]C)(<[:230]D)}}
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

PS: Thanks to appropriate personal protective equipment (safety glasses and a  lab coat) no ducks were harmed during the experiments...

The code for the erlenmeyer flask is heavily inspired frome this question: [tikz and \pgfdeclareshape why the text is not at the center anchor?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303295/134144)

Comment: Fantastic! I hope the duck does not blow up anything :)

Comment: FYI: the next version of the tikzducks will include buttons for the lab coat  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXN1a.png

Comment: @samcarter: As long as the duck keeps in mind the hazard and precautionary statements, nothing will be blown up by accident. Thanks for including the buttons. With them the lab coat looks a lot more realistic.

Answer (score 26):

**Moebius Duck's evocation**

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85,tikzducks,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\foreach \frame in {0,...,81} {%

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{mod(\frame,41)}

\ifthenelse{\x>64 \OR \x<4}{\def\Orient{-1}}{\def\Orient{1}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x  = {(1cm,0cm)},
                    y  = {(45:.5cm)},
                    z  = {(0cm,1.5cm)},
                    scale=3]

\foreach \L [count=\z from -2, evaluate=\z as \y using \z/4 ] in {A,...,E} {%
    \foreach \x [count=\n from 0] in {0,9,...,360} {%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\T}{1+0.5*\y*cos(\x/2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{\T*cos(\x)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{\T*sin(\x)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Z}{0.5*\y*sin(\x/2)}
        \path (\X,\Y,\Z) coordinate (\L\n)
            ;
    }
}


    \ifthenelse{\frame=62 \OR \frame=63}{%
    \begin{scope}[x={(1cm,0cm)},
                    y={(0cm,1cm)},
                    shift={($(C\x)-(.05,.03)$)},
                    scale=.05]
    \duck
    \end{scope}}{}



\foreach \i  [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1),
            evaluate=\i as \K using 80-30*cos(9*(\i-22.5))
            ] in {0,1,...,39} {%
    \ifthenelse{\frame=18 \AND \i>17 \AND \i<20}{%
    \begin{scope}[x={(1cm,0cm)},
                    y={(0cm,1cm)},
                    shift={($(C18)-(.05,.03)$)},
                    scale=.05]
    \duck
    \end{scope}}{}
    \draw[smooth,gray,fill=orange!25!white!\K!blue]
                (A\i) -- (E\i) -- (E\j) -- (A\j) -- cycle ;
    \draw[smooth,gray] (B\i) -- (B\j) (D\i) -- (D\j) ;
    \draw[smooth,thick] (C\i) -- (C\j) ;
}

    \ifthenelse{\frame<18 \OR \frame>63}{%
    \begin{scope}[x={(1cm,0cm)},
                    y={(0cm,1cm)},
                    shift={($(C\x)-(.05,.03)$)},
                    scale=.05]
    \duck
    \end{scope}}{}


\end{tikzpicture}   }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Every time the duck passes I go *wheeeeeeeeeeeeeeee*

Comment: What is wheeeeeeeeeeeeeeee in dukc's language ?

Comment: similar to IE here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuvxuoXK-_g `:)`

Answer (score 21):

**Ducks preserve the amount of movement**

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks,luatex85,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


\newcommand{\Duck}[1]{%
\begin{scope}[scale=\scl,shift={(-1.05,-1.075)}]
\clip (.1,.1) rectangle (2.1,2.15) ;
\coordinate (dck) at (1.05,1.075) ;
\duck
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[gray!25] (dck) -- (A#1) ;
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\begin{document}

\def\pas{.434}
\def\scl{.22}

\foreach \x in {-9,...,9,8,7,...,-8} {%


\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[use as bounding box] (-2,0) rectangle (4,1.5) ;

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using (\i-1)*\pas] in {0,...,6} {%
\coordinate[] (A\i) at (\j,1.5) ;
\fill (A\i) circle (1pt) ;
}

\ifthenelse{\x<0}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\L}{-90+60*sin(10*\x)}
    \gdef\R{-90}
    }{%
    \gdef\L{-90}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{-90+60*sin(10*\x)}
    }

\begin{scope}[shift=($(A6)+(\R:1.5)$)]
\Duck{6}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift=($(A0)+(\L:1.5)$)]
\Duck{0}
\end{scope}


\foreach \i in {1,...,5} {%
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\pas*\i cm -\pas cm]
    \Duck{\i}
    \end{scope}
}


\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really awesome!

Answer (score 16):

I will admit that this was slightly inspired by this question, but here is a genuine worksheet that I used today.

[image: Projectiles with ducks]

Comment: Are you sure this duck didn't get harmed?

Comment: @gusbrs It was given the Easter egg as a reward for all its hard work.

Comment: Ah!, just like the human cannonball, I see.  :)  But I suppose it is fair to admit `tikzducks` are even more resistant than rubber-ducks.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 15):

**The Doppler Duck's affect**

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85,tikzducks,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


\begin{document}

\foreach \i [count=\frame from 1] in {-12.5,...,12.5} {

\ifthenelse{\frame>14}{\def\K{blue}}{\def\K{red}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\X{15}
\def\Y{2}

\filldraw[gray!50,transform canvas={xslant=2}] (-\X,-\Y) -- (\X,-\Y) -- (\X,\Y) -- (-\X,\Y) -- cycle ;


\draw[line width=5pt,
    white,
    transform canvas={xslant=2},
    dash pattern=on 20mm off 8mm] (-\X,0) -- (\X,0) ;

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\i,-.9)},xscale=-1]
    \ifthenelse{\frame=14}{%
        \duck[speech={Coin !},bubblecolour=white!95!yellow]}{%
        \duck
        }
    \coordinate (LH) at (wing) ;
    \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \begin{scope}[shift={(-\i,.6)}]
    \duck
    \coordinate (RH) at (wing) ;
    \end{scope}

    \path[decoration={%
    markings,% switch on markings
    mark=between positions .18 and .98 step 0.2 with {
        \draw[ultra thick,\K] (0,0)
            arc (0:15:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) ;
        \draw[ultra thick,\K] (0,0)
            arc (0:-15:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) ;
        }
    },
    postaction={decorate}] (LH) -- (RH) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

**The redshift version :**

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85,tikzducks,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,backgrounds}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


\begin{document}

\foreach \i [count=\frame from 1] in {-12.5,...,12.5} {

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Koeff}{100*cos(\i/15*90)}

\ifthenelse{\frame<14}{%
    \def\K{yellow!\Koeff!blue}}{%
    \def\K{yellow!\Koeff!red}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\X{15}
\def\Y{2}

\filldraw[gray!50,transform canvas={xslant=2}] (-\X,-\Y) -- (\X,-\Y) -- (\X,\Y) -- (-\X,\Y) -- cycle ;


\draw[line width=5pt,
    white,
    transform canvas={xslant=2},
    dash pattern=on 20mm off 8mm] (-\X,0) -- (\X,0) ;

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\i,-.9)},xscale=-1]
    \ifthenelse{\frame=14}{%
        \duck[body=\K,speech={Coin !},bubblecolour=white!95!yellow]}{%
        \duck[body=\K]
        }
    \coordinate (LH) at (wing) ;
    \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \begin{scope}[shift={(-\i,.6)}]
    \duck[body=\K]
    \coordinate (RH) at (wing) ;
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Tarass Amazing!

Comment: @samcarter I wonder if you plane to make a rotative duck shape, let say every 45° ? and btw, duck looses his eyes with `xshift=-1`, but not with `xscale=-1`, also with `rotate around y`.

Comment: I'll give it a +1 for the idea, and −1 for the scientific content. Those sound waves, if that is what they are, don't behave like sound waves! But there is potential here.

Comment: @Tarass Do you have a MWE of the duck losing its eyes? `\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1]
\duck
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} ` works fine for me

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen and for light redshift ?

Comment: @Tarass For red shifted light it might be easier to understand if the ducks move towards or away from the observer and change their colour.

Comment: @samcarter sorry, was `\begin{scope}[x=-1cm]`.

Comment: Don't the ducks see a red shift when moving apart, and a blue shift when approaching each other?

Comment: I will do that too.

Answer (score 13):

### Visualization of a sinus function

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %probably not needed ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={128mm,96mm},margin=0.5cm} %\textwidth=11.8, \textheight=8.6
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xfp}
\tikzstyle{witchstars}=[star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25, draw,inner sep=1.3pt,anchor=outer point 3]



\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \fill[DeepSkyBlue3] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
 \pgfmathsetseed{2}
 \end{tikzpicture}}}

\newcommand\loopmax{30}

\foreach \z in {1,2,...,\loopmax}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\textheight);
\begin{scope}[scale=2]
%\draw[domain=0:10, black,smooth]   plot (\x,{sin(\x r)+0.5}) ;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[overlay,
              xshift=\fpeval{0.67-\z*(0.67/\loopmax)}\textwidth,
              yshift=\fpeval{sin(\z/\loopmax*2*pi)+0.5}cm ]
\begin{scope}[scale=2]

\duck[witch=black!50!gray,
longhair=red!80!black,
jacket=black!50!gray,
magicwand]
\fill[red] (0,0) node[witchstars,fill=red,inner sep=2.3pt]{};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\foreach \y in {1,2,...,\loopmax}{%
 \begin{scope}[overlay,
              xshift=\fpeval{0.67-\y*(0.67/\loopmax)}\textwidth,
              yshift=\fpeval{sin(\y/\loopmax*2*pi)+0.5}cm ]
 \fill[] (0,0) node[witchstars,fill=yellow,inner sep=1.3pt]{};
 \end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}\newpage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you rotate the duck as it travels along the curve you can show that the derivative is the cosine as well.

Answer (score 12):

It can be used to illustrate Occam's razor, which could be argued to be the epitome of scientific guessing:

> If it looks like a duck, floats like a duck, and bobs its head like a duck, then obviously it is a duck! (Even if it is just a toy duck.)
>
> [image: toy duck]

Comment: Of course this raises the very tricky question of whether a "toy duck" is in fact a duck.

Comment: @AlanMunn: That's a very interesting question, and incidentally I thought a lot about that very question before. My conclusion is that linguistically a "toy duck" is in fact a "duck", because an adjective can be treated as a function that on an input noun phrase produces an output that is also a noun phrase, appropriately modified from the input. There are 2 sorts of adjectives. One sort is an operator on its domain; its domain is closed under it. The other sort is not an operator on its domain. The adjective "toy" is an operator, while the adjective "fake" is not.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Anyway, I deliberately made the example comical, rather than serious, and it's up to the dear reader to come up with the hard questions in philosophy of science/language. =D

Comment: Well as my dissertation advisor once said: which would you prefer to be shot with, a gun or a toy gun?  So it's not clear that 'toy' is substantially different from 'fake'.

Comment: @AlanMunn: You're making a fallacious argument here. A brown duck is a duck. And a yellow duck is also a duck. But a brown duck is certainly not a yellow duck. Similarly, a toy gun is a gun, but that does not mean all guns are identical to a toy gun.

Comment: I'm not really interested in having a serious debate about this in SE comments. You brought up the idea of different sorts of adjectives (which is definitely on the right track). I was just pointing out that 'toy' and 'fake' behave a lot more alike than 'fake' and 'red'. There are at least 4 different types of adjectives, semantically, *intersective*, (like 'red'), *subsective* like ('skillful') and (at least two types) of  non-subsective, non-intersectives (like 'former' and 'fake'.) See https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8e12/7df875b4f56500138839403b583d258102e6.pdf for some discussion.

Comment: @AlanMunn: We can continue discussion in [this chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art). Thanks for your linked PDF, but it in fact states clearly that evidence points towards the 'standard' classification as inaccurate. I maintain that "toy gun" is substantially different from "fake gun" because "toy" in "toy gun" restricts "gun" to include only those that are toys, while "fake" in "fake gun" actually produces a distinct concept rather than merely restricting the "gun" concept. Compare "toy model" and "fake model". =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75062/discussion-between-alan-munn-and-user21820).

Comment: Your conclusion may be correct, but the reasoning which got you there is not: *toy* is not an adjective. *Toy duck* is a noun phrase constructed with two nouns.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: That's an interesting claim, which I reject. Many lexicons agree with me that one of the meanings of "toy" is as an adjective, such as http://www.dictionary.com/browse/toy and https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toy and https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/toy_2.

Comment: It's a shame they don't provide any justification for such an astonishing claim. The word *toy* doesn't do any of the things that distinguish adjectives: it can't form comparatives ("more toy" / "toyer", "too toy", "how toy?"), nor adverbs ("toyly"), nor follow a copula ("this duck is toy"). The most surprising of those you list is the last, because the full Oxford English Dictionary lists *toy* only as a noun and a verb.

Comment: @PeterTaylor These comments would have been better off in the chatroom for this thread.  But for the purposes of the semantics being discussed, it's very likely that the Noun vs Adj distinction is not relevant.  As long as 'toy' in 'toy gun' is a noun modifier an not part of an N-N compound noun (which it's not) the semantics can be the same.  But I agree with you totally that 'toy' is never an adjective.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: You should just come join our discussion in the chat-room! I suppose if you require an adjective to be able to act as a substantive (as in "is toy") and to form comparatives, then indeed "toy" is not. However, I disagree that all adjectives must be as you imply (in real language), such as "main" and "utmost" and "sheer". If you reject these as adjectives, what do you call them?

Answer (score 9):

Here are some ducks illustrating the need for sidelobe supression in radar. (I may have been a little bit inspired by this question, but I used this in a real presentation.)

[image: radar ducks]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

%%% extract coordinate
\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}        
{\YCoord};}%

%%% Waves, source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423489/concentric-circle-segments-between-two-points-in-tikz/423567#423567 
%#1=Number of waves
%#2 ans #3 point A and B
%#4 Angle of first wave
%#5 Colour of waves
\def\NumSignalsFromToAngle#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \def\NumberSignals{#1}
    \ExtractCoordinate{#2}
    \xdef\Xa{\XCoord}
    \xdef\Ya{\YCoord}
    \ExtractCoordinate{#3}
    \xdef\Xb{\XCoord}
    \xdef\Yb{\YCoord}
    \def\lw {2} %line width
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{10*sqrt((\Xb/10-\Xa/10)^2+(\Yb/10-\Ya/10)^2)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\step{\dist/\NumberSignals}
    \def\offset{0.02*\dist}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\AngleFromAToB{\ifdim\Xb>\Xa atan((\Yb/10-\Ya/10)/(\Xb/10 -\Xa/10))\else \ifdim \Xb<\Xa 180+atan((\Yb/10-\Ya/10)/(\Xb/10 -\Xa/10))\else\ifdim\Ya>\Yb -90\else90\fi\fi\fi}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\NumberSignals}
        {%
        \coordinate(Point) at ($(#2)+({((\step pt)*(2*\i-1)/2-\offset)*cos(\AngleFromAToB) },{(((\step pt)*(2*\i-1)/2-\offset)*sin(\AngleFromAToB)})$);
        \pgfmathsetmacro\r{\step/2*(2*\i-1)}
        %\l_1=\l_i => \angle_i=\angle_1/(2i-1)
        \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{#4/(2*\i-1)}
        \draw[line width = \lw, #5]  (Point) arc (\AngleFromAToB:    {\AngleFromAToB+\angle/2}:\r pt);
        \draw[line width = \lw, #5]  (Point) arc (\AngleFromAToB:{\AngleFromAToB-\angle/2}:\r pt);
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %%% radar
    \def\h{2} %height
    \def\xd{0.5} %x-depth
    \def\yd{0.12} %y-depth
    \def\xw{1.2}   %x-width
    \def\yw{1} %y-width
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at ($(A) + (\xd,\yd) $);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(B) + (0,\h)$);
    \coordinate (D) at ($(A) + (0,\h)$);
    \coordinate (E) at ($(A) + (-\xw, \yw)$);
    \coordinate (F) at ($(E) + (0, \h)$);
    \coordinate (G) at ($(F) + (\xd,\yd)$);

    \shade[bottom color=gray!90, top color=black!30](A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A);
    \shade[bottom color=gray!80, top color=black!10](A) -- (D) -- (F) -- (E) -- (A);
    \shade[bottom color=gray!80, top color=black!10] (D) -- (C) -- (G) -- (F) -- (D);

    \coordinate (radar) at ($ (A) !0.5! (F)$);

    %%% graduate duck
    \coordinate (T) at ($ (radar) + (-5,0) $);
    \begin{scope}[shift = {($(T) + (-1,-0.4)$)}, scale = 0.5]
        \duck[book=\scalebox{0.6}{$\beta$},
            bookcolour=blue!60!red!70!white,graduate=gray!20!black,
            tassel=red!70!black];
    \end{scope}
    \NumSignalsFromToAngle{6}{radar}{T}{130}{blue!70}
    \NumSignalsFromToAngle{6}{T}{radar}{130}{red!70}
    \coordinate (midpos) at ($(radar) !0.5! (T) $);
    \node[single arrow,fill=red!50, above = of midpos]  {\scriptsize reflected};
    \node[single arrow,fill=blue!50, below = of midpos, shape border rotate = 180]  {\scriptsize emitted};

    %%% kulturman duck 
    \coordinate (T) at ($ (radar) + (-2,2) $);
    \coordinate (R) at ($ (radar) + (0,\h/3) $);
    \begin{scope}[shift = {($(T) + (+0.2,-0.3)$)}, yscale=.5,xscale=-.5]
        \duck[crazyhair, wine=red!70!black];
    \end{scope}
    \NumSignalsFromToAngle{3}{T}{R}{130}{red!70}

    %%% mirror duck
    \coordinate (T) at ($ (radar) + (-0.5,-1.5) $);
    \coordinate (R) at ($ (radar) + (0,-\h/3) $);
    \begin{scope}[shift = {($(T) + (-1,-1)$)}, scale = 0.5]
        \duck[beret=red!40!blue!90!white, signpost, signback=white!80!brown];
    \end{scope}
    \NumSignalsFromToAngle{2}{R}{T}{130}{blue!50}
    \NumSignalsFromToAngle{2}{T}{R}{130}{red!70}

    %%% mystery duck
    \coordinate (T) at ($ (radar) + (-6,-2) $);
    \coordinate (R) at (radar);%($ (radar) + (\xw/2,-\h/3) $);
    \begin{scope}[shift = {($(T) + (0,-0.5)$)}, yscale=.5,xscale=-.5]
        \duck[mask=black,cape=black];
    \end{scope}
    \NumSignalsFromToAngle{7}{T}{R}{130}{red!70}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Dispersion of water waves

This answer can be seen as an extension to [the answer for the Cherenkov effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422990). The effect is observed in the real world ([just search for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=dispersion%20of%20water%20wave%20duck&tbm=isch) or look into the [relevant Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake) [articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(water_waves))), when ducks (or boats, or anthing else) swim.

If a duck just sits in the water and wobbles up and down, we can observe circles of water waves. (*the code for this duck is easily found in the manual*)

[image: wobbling duck]

But when the duck swims with a (constant) velocity and naturally continues to wobble/continues to excite waves, these circles all have different origins. We would expect something like in [the answer for the Cherenkov effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422990): 
Only in two direction for each wabe circle, there is a positive interference and two wavefronts should appear. The opening angle of the depends on the speed of the duck and the propagation speed of the water wave.

[image: swimming duck in dispersion-free water]

But this is not what is observed in reality! Water waves have a frequency-dependent speed of propagation (aka dispersion), and each emitted pulse (here denoted in time steps `$\delta t$`) has a group velocity and a *different* phase velocity. The angle where the constructive interference happens is determined by the groupd velocity because this one determines where the pulse is currently travelling, but inside this pulse, the phase velocity determines how the wavefront is oriented.

Overall, this leads to a picture like the following one.

[image: swimming duck in real water]

The angles are not correct because I am too lazy (I think, they are quite fixed due to physics.) Also the wavefront shape is probably not perfect.

Code for the first part

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[rotate=30,] 
  \draw[gray] 
    (8,6) circle (3.55)
    (6,6) circle (2.68) 
    (4,6) circle (1.8) 
    (2,6) circle (0.9)     
  ;
  \draw [<->,very thick,gray] (2,6) -- (4,6) node[midway,above,rotate=30] {$v_\mathrm{duck}\Delta t$} ;
  \draw [<->,very thick,gray] (4,6) -- (6,6) node[midway,above,rotate=30] {$v_\mathrm{duck}\Delta t$} ;
  \draw [<->,very thick,gray] (6,6) -- (8,6) node[midway,above,rotate=30] {$v_\mathrm{duck}\Delta t$} ;
  \draw [ ->,very thick] (2,6) -- ({2-0.90*sin(28)},{6-0.90*cos(28)}) node[midway,right,rotate=00] {$v_\mathrm{wave}\Delta t$};
  \draw [ ->,very thick] (4,6) -- ({4-1.80*sin(28)},{6-1.80*cos(28)}) node[midway,above,rotate=-90] {$2v_\mathrm{wave}\Delta t$};
  \draw [ ->,very thick] (6,6) -- ({6-2.68*sin(28)},{6-2.68*cos(28)}) node[midway,above,rotate=-90] {$3v_\mathrm{wave}\Delta t$};
  \draw [ ->,very thick] (8,6) -- ({8-3.55*sin(28)},{6-3.55*cos(28)}) node[midway,above,rotate=-90] {$4v_\mathrm{wave}\Delta t$};
  \draw[blue,thick] (12,0) -- (0,6) -- (12,12);
  \draw[gray,dashed]  (0,6) -- (15,6);
  \draw (-.5,6) pic[scale=0.75] {duck};
  \end{scope}  


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Similar Code for the second part

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[rotate=30,] 
  \draw[gray] 
    (8,6) circle (3.55)
    (6,6) circle (2.68) 
    (4,6) circle (1.8) 
    (2,6) circle (0.9)     
  ;
  \begin{scope}
  \clip (0,6) -- (1,7) -- (11,12) -- (11,11) -- (1,6) -- cycle;
  \foreach \x in {0.7,1.4,...,5}{
  \draw[ultra thick,blue] (\x,6) -- (\x+7,6+7);
  }
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
  \clip (0,6) -- (1,5) -- (11,0) -- (11,1) -- (1,6) -- cycle;
  \foreach \x in {0.7,1.4,...,5}{
  \draw[ultra thick,blue] (\x,6) -- (\x+7,6-7);
  }
  \end{scope}
  \draw[blue!50!gray,semithick] (12,0) -- (0,6) -- (12,12);
  \draw[gray,dashed]  (0,6) -- (15,6);
  \draw (-.5,6) pic[scale=0.75] {duck};
  \end{scope}  


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```