# Tikz Node Style: half square, half ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I was just wondering if there is a way to change the border style of a node so that one half is, for example, a rectangle and the other an ellipse or cloud or something. The image below visualizes this:

[image: node (left half: rectangle, right half: ellipse]

Does someone out there has an idea how to achieve this?

BACKGROUND:
I want to use the borderstyle to define the element described by a node, e.g. a rectangle node denotes an element of type X, a node with an ellipse border denotes an element of type Y, and an element that has both types X and Y should be half rectangle, half ellipse. I know how to draw rectangles, ellipses, clouds, etc. but how can I merge them into one style?

Comment: Did you try with `rounded reectangle` from the `shapes.misc` tikzlibrary? It's not elliptical, but it could fit your need. If not, you may try by drawing a pic and putting nodes on it. It's quite tedious but depending on what you need to use your node for, it could be a good idea. Please be more specific about your goal, so that we could help you.

Comment: Thank you, I have added background information to my question. I take a look at your mentioned library.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! Perhaps this post can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580026/creating-an-ellipse-rectangle-shaped-node-in-tikz

Comment: Unfortunately, even if pic would be a solution, this does not provide all that `node` does, especially anchors. But depending on how you want to link these nodes, you can manage to create anchors in a pic.

Comment: @Juan Castaño: this is exactly what I was looking for. (NBur's answer, not the pic version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you my two cents, just in case.

### 1. With shapes.misc library

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            
        \node[
            draw,
            rounded corners=3pt,
            minimum width=3cm,
            minimum height=2cm,
            rounded rectangle,
            rounded rectangle left arc=none,
            font=\sffamily\Large] {Hello};

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Fancy node 1]

### 2. With a pic and manually inserted anchors

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \tikzset%
            {
            pin/.style={Circle[]-,red},
            rectell/.pic={              
                \draw (0,0.5*3) coordinate(-north) -| (-0.5*5,0) coordinate(-west) |- (0,-0.5*3) coordinate(-south) arc(-90:0:0.5*5 cm and 0.5*3 cm) coordinate(-east) arc(0:90:0.5*5 cm and 0.5*3 cm) -- cycle;
                \node (-center) at (0,0) {#1}; 
                }
            }
        
        \draw (0,0) pic(A){rectell={\sffamily\Huge Hello}};
        
        \draw[pin] (A-center.center) --++ (3,3) node[above] {A-center};
        \draw[pin] (A-north) --++ (-1,1) node[above] {A-north};
        \draw[pin] (A-west) --++ (-1,1) node[above] {A-west};
        \draw[pin] (A-south) --++ (-1,-1) node[below] {A-south};
        \draw[pin] (A-east) --++ (1,1) node[above] {A-east};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Fancy node 2]

Complete code with preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
            
        \node[
            draw,
            rounded corners=3pt,
            minimum width=3cm,
            minimum height=2cm,
            rounded rectangle,
            rounded rectangle left arc=none,
            font=\sffamily\Large] {Hello};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
    \bigskip
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \tikzset%
            {
            pin/.style={Circle[]-,red},
            rectell/.pic={              
                \draw (0,0.5*3) coordinate(-north) -| (-0.5*5,0) coordinate(-west) |- (0,-0.5*3) coordinate(-south) arc(-90:0:0.5*5 cm and 0.5*3 cm) coordinate(-east) arc(0:90:0.5*5 cm and 0.5*3 cm) -- cycle;
                \node (-center) at (0,0) {#1}; 
                }
            }
        
        \draw (0,0) pic(A){rectell={\sffamily\Huge Hello}};
        
        \draw[pin] (A-center.center) --++ (3,3) node[above] {A-center};
        \draw[pin] (A-north) --++ (-1,1) node[above] {A-north};
        \draw[pin] (A-west) --++ (-1,1) node[above] {A-west};
        \draw[pin] (A-south) --++ (-1,-1) node[below] {A-south};
        \draw[pin] (A-east) --++ (1,1) node[above] {A-east};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT: A PARAMETRIC PIC USED *AS A NODE*

If you want to draw a pic *node* and choose width and height, you can pass those parameters as arguments to the pic whan you call it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \tikzset%
            {
            pin/.style={Circle[]-,red},
            %
            pics/rectell/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{code = {                
                \draw (0,0.5*#3) coordinate(-north) -| (-0.5*#2,0) coordinate(-west) |- (0,-0.5*#3) coordinate(-south) arc(-90:0:0.5*#2 cm and 0.5*#3 cm) coordinate(-east) arc(0:90:0.5*#2 cm and 0.5*#3 cm) -- cycle;
                \coordinate (-center) at (0,0) node {#1}; 
                }}
            }
        
        \draw (0,0) pic(A){rectell={\sffamily\Huge Width 7 Height 3}/7/3};
        
        \draw[pin] (A-center) --++ (3,2) node[above] {A-center};
        \draw[pin] (A-north) --++ (-1,1) node[above] {A-north};
        \draw[pin] (A-west) --++ (-1,1) node[above] {A-west};
        \draw[pin] (A-south) --++ (-1,-1) node[below] {A-south};
        \draw[pin] (A-east) --++ (1,1) node[above] {A-east};
        
        \draw (0,-6) pic{rectell={\sffamily\Huge W 4 H 5}/4/5};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Args for pic]

Comment: Thank you for your detailled suggestion. I didn't work with pics before, so how could I cange the height of a pic? Simply by adding minimum height to the node in tikzset? Or has this to be done with by setting the drawing parameters?

Comment: Unfortunately, pics don't work like nodes. You can either change the lengths into the pic declaration or pass them as parameters.

Comment: Okay, I was afraid of this. So I'll go for your first solution. Thanks

Comment: I just edited my post to add the solution to pass lengths as arguments. It's not too worrying, in my opinion ;)